# Spacing LinearLayouts equally by the maximum height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a table row defined in XML file.
It contains 3 `LinearLayout' one on top of the other:
I would like to get this look:

```
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|              a                |
|                               |
|                               |
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|              b                |
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|              c                |
|-------------------------------|
```

The "problem" is that the `LinearLayout` "a" might expand and be at different heights while "b" and "c" are always in the same height.

I would to find the maximum height of the `LinearLayout`'s and to enforce this height to be the height of all the other `LinearLayout`'s too, so I will get this look for each row:

```
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|              a                |
|                               |
|                               |
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|              b                |
|                               |
|                               |
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|              c                |
|                               |
|                               |
|-------------------------------|
```

I tried using `android:layout_weight` with no success...

Any ideas?

Comment: layout_weight is the right way to go, how did you try to use it?

Comment: To get `android:layout_weight` to work correctly, you must set the `android:layout_height` of each `LinearLayout` to be `0dp`.

Comment: I've tried all the variations with `android:layout_height` (0dp, wrap_content, ...) with no success - I always got the same unwanted look. In the meanwhile I gave the top parent fixed `dp` size and now it's obviously working, but this is not the optimal way of doing this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement this in one example. 
Here is what I did :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        >
           <TextView 
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hjadsh haksj hasjk haksj hjkas hkjas hjkas hkjas "
            android:textColor="#000000"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        ></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff"
        ></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I used the textview in the first layout to show that it works as what you need. 
You can also fixed the height of the layout b & c to make them of fixed height and vary layout a by setting layout_height:wrap_content

You can now customized it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"  >  
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00ffff"
    ></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    ></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```